# Unable to double tap on the trackpad to highlight multiple words in macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, trackpad, accessibility

In previous versions of OS X, I was able to "double tap" on the trackpad and then move my finger to the side or down to highlight/select text/multiple text.

I'm unable to duplicate this in the new macOS Mojave.  Previously, I'd enable System Preferences > Trackpad > "Tap to click".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Although not specific to Mojave, this link helped me out.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6295852

System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options > "Enable dragging" [without drag lock].
[image]