# How to enable "tap to click" using keyboard only?

Tags: trackpad

My trackpad started to work incorrectly: when I double-clicked and draged, I couldn't select text anymore. Even though when I just double-clicked a word, it was being selected as usual.

I tried to troubleshoot this issue and went into Trackpad preferences. I tapped "Tap to click" option, and now I cannot click anything at all! And I cannot turn the option back ON. Also, I don't have a mouse to connect...

**Question**

How to turn "tap to click" back ON using only keyboard?

**Versions**

- Mac OS X 10.14.6 Build 18G3020
- MBP 13" 2017

Comment: Do you have "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls" enabled?

Comment: For the selection problem the solution is [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348706/unable-to-double-tap-on-the-trackpad-to-highlight-multiple-words-in-macos-mojave). It's due to a recent update of macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it via Terminal.app with those commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking -bool true
```

You may need to restart the System after that. Or, run the following:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, though. I can read this flag as `true`, but when I go to the preferences, "Tap to click" is still unchecked.

Comment: This is what worked for me: `defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking -bool true`. From [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/31/turn-on-mac-touch-to-click-command-line/). Thanks! Restart was needed.

Comment: I Didn't know about that, I've edited the answer :)

Comment: Adding to this: According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414836/130792), you can make `defaults write` take effect without logout-login/restarting with `activateSettings -u`